# Specify ruby version for project

Tags: ruby

What is the recommended way of specifying which ruby version an application uses?
Heroku recommends adding it to the Gemfile, e.g.

```
ruby "2.0.0"
```

`rbenv` however seems to look for a `.ruby-version`file.

I would like to make sure that developers will be using the same interpreter regardless of their preferred suite of ruby managers, IDE's, platforms, etc...

Comment: Bundler will raise an exception if your current Ruby doesn't match the one specified in the Gemfile

Comment: Just add it to your Gemfile, as you've already suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can never be absolutely sure that they are using the version you want. Even if you added an exception in the application boot code that checks for the version at runtime, they could easily bypass it.

Thus said, you should keep the `.ruby-version` as it's used by RVM, rbenv *and* chruby, which are very likely that the other developers in your team use.

Comment: My colleagues aren't evil, so that's cool. :-) We are just looking for ways to make sure the reference ruby interpreter is declared and that our tools will automatically pick it up, so us lazy devs don't have to do it ourselves. :-) When you have tens of projects spanning Ruby 1.8.7 to 2.1, it's tiresome to (remember to) switch all the time.

Comment: So the `.ruby-version` file is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I use `rvm` like so:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

or

```
rvm use jruby
```

before running the program

Comment: This is not what the question is about. Developers know how to change ruby interpreters. What I am looking for is the recommended way of declaring the ruby version and ensuring that developers run the app using that version automatically without having to manually switch like you are doing here.